# How can I read / write Alternate Data Streams on a Google Drive (on Windows)?

Tags: ntfs, google-drive, alternate-data-stream

I have a windows box with Google Drive set up to stream files to local `G:` (default behaviour).

When I download files from the internet and save them to my local Google Drive, they have the usual windows warning about their source (normally reset by clicking `unblock` from the File Properties window). This has undesirable knock-on effects in my attempts to automate workflow. I am led to believe that this information is stored in NTFS Alternate Data Streams (ADS).

I've tried using the sysinternals **streams** utility to access that, but it reports that `the specified volume does not support streams.`

I've tried accessing using PowerShell, after reading [this article](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/scripting/8888/friday-fun-with-powershell-and-alternate-data-streams/), but am getting no joy:
`Get-Item .\some-file-name.mp3 -Stream *` returns `Get-Item : The parameter is incorrect`.

The manual option (right-click the file in Explorer, choose Properties, then "Unblock") is still available and works fine.

I'd like to automate removal of the *downloaded from the internet* flag somehow, and would prefer to avoid moving the file elsewhere, setting the flag, then moving it back. Is that my only option?

(Annoyingly, google searches for this are made harder because "ADS" is also interpreted "ads", as in adverts - so unless articles use the full name *Alternate Data Streams* then they're hard to locate.)

Comment: What do you mean *"When I download files there"* aren't all files visible there and they are opened when you press to open, what do you mean by "download"? Also, you mention *"normally reset by clicking unblock from the File Properties window"*, is this manual Unblock option available on those files for you?

Comment: Ultimately, what's likely happening (if we are indeed dealing with ADS) is that the ADS is on the cached file (someone in your user profile data, probably under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\DriveFS`) and not on the Drove Stream file (which is simply like a shortcut)

Comment: Thanks, @YisroelTech. I mean "when I download files from the internet and save them to my google drive (which then syncs to the cloud)". I will edit the question to reflect that.
You are probably right about the files in DriveFS being the source of the ADS data. Unfortunately, those files are all anonymised to sequential alphanumeric names, so I'm not going to find it that way!
It may be that I have to download to a proper NTFS drive, remove the ADS, then move to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since your main problem is to be able to unblock a file from
the internet in a workflow, you may use PowerShell for that.

The command to use is
[Unblock-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.3),
described as:

> The Unblock-File cmdlet lets you open files that were downloaded from the internet. It unblocks PowerShell script files that were downloaded from the internet so you can run them, even when the PowerShell execution policy is RemoteSigned. By default, these files are blocked to protect the computer from untrusted files.

The command can be used in various ways.
Below are found two examples.

Unblock one file:

```
Unblock-File -Path C:\Users\User01\Documents\Downloads\PowerShellTips.chm
```

Unblock multiple files:

```
dir C:\Downloads\*PowerShell* | Unblock-File
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Will try later and accept answer if it works on Google drive...